# fedex api for php

Tags: php, fedex

I am using  FedEx api I have created the my account on FedEx.

My problem is that when I am using test account number and test meter number I am getting the results properly, but when I am using client account detail I always get the error invalid header (invalid header).

When I have contact with the FedEx team, they said me to use different URL ( before asking with support team I am using this URL https://gatewaybeta.fedex.com/GatewayDC now they have asked me to use this URL  gateway.fedex.com:443/gatewayDC )
but still the same response

Does one have any idea about this or have any API regarding FedEx shipping charge. I have to to find only shipping rate with this API

Comment: How about getting back to the Fedex team again and telling them the new URL isn't working?

Comment: There is a PHP Class at http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1276-PHP-Interface-to-FedEx-Ship-Manager.html which may help you with this issue.